# Trying to restrict access to 'logged-in' page using JavaScript and Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, facebook

**Edited JavaScript file and added routes to suggest possible asset-pipeline interference. Problem remains unresolved.**

**I am using the Facebook SDK to log users into my Rails app. As of right now I have the app functioning to when a user logs in, the application redirects them to the 'logged-in' page**

**The problem I am having is restricting anybody from accessing the 'logged-in' page before logging in.**

**The `response.status` for the `checkLoginState();` function returns 'connected' when the user has logged in, and returns 'unknown' when the user is not logged in. In my `checkLoginStatus();` function, only the first conditional statement containing the logic `if (response.status === 'connected')` is executing, while the `else && else if (response.status === 'unknown')` logic is being ignored.**

**JavaScript**

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected'){
        window.location.href = '/logged_in'
      } else {
        window.location.href = '/';
      }
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<MyApp-ID>',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log("NAME: " + response.name);
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

  function logout(){
    FB.logout(function(response) {
      window.location.href = '/';
    });
  }
```

**HTML index/log-in page**

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
```

**HTML logged-in page**

```
<div onload="checkLoginState();">
  <h1>Logged In</h1>
  <button onclick="logout();">Logout</button>
</div>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/' => 'pages#signup'
  get 'logged_in' => 'pages#logged_in'
end
```

**What I have attempted to do is add the `onload='checkLoginState();'` to the div and also the body inside the `logged-in` page with `checkLoginState();` returning 'unknown' and the logic directing `window.location.href = '/';` to be executed.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "success" (the login status is checked and returned "connected") occurs in the testAPI() function. Have you tried adding the conditions there?

Edit -

Did you try adding your conditions in the function that calls the statusChangeCallback() function?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // etc.
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the same thoughts, but when I tried that functionality the page would reload over and over again and was still accessible. The same thing happened when I tried to add the logic to the statusChangeCallback() function.

Comment: What did you add to testAPI()? Just add the success redirect to "/logged_in". Why do you need two different conditions for if a user isn't logged in when they both do the same thing? What if you set a cookie for a connected user and check if the cookie exists on load of the logged in page?

Comment: I added: `window.location.href = '/logged_in'` in the testAPI() function. It causes the page to continuously loop. I am following the FB dev-docs.

Comment: See edit. Added another idea. If this doesn't work, this seems like the same sort of issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001347/auto-redirect-after-facebook-login-with-javascript-sdk

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I have tried adding the logic to the `getLoginStatus();` function as well, which causes the page to continuously reload. I have even tried to create a new function to handle this but still could not solve issue.

Comment: The link I posted seems to have resolved the other person's issue.

Comment: For some reason, adding the `window.location.href = '/logged_in';` action causes the page to continuously reload using the logic from the link.